# Flutter - Divider widget changing width based on screen position

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use the [Divider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) class. It seems that its rendered width is changing based on where it is on the screen even though I have explicitly set the width.

I have the following code (which I've simplified a bit):

```
class HistoryListState extends State<HistoryList> {
  // use this function to generate the list of widgets used as a label for each list item
  // each label consists of the workout name, a divider, and the first 3 exercises
  List<Widget> generateLabel(TrackedWorkout workout) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [
      Text(workout.name),

      // DIVIDER IN QUESTION
      const Divider(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
        thickness: 1,
      ),
    ];

    for (int i = 0; i < workout.exercises.length; i++) {
      if (i > 2) {
        widgets.add(const Text('...'));
        break;
      }

      widgets.add(Text(workout.exercises[i].name));
    }

    return widgets;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.workouts.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: generateLabel(widget.workouts[index]),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[Video demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B84MH.jpg)

As you can see, initially, each divider has slightly different widths. Then when the list is scrolled, the dividers change widths too.

Comment: You meant thickness not width. I just think it is fine and won't create that much of an issue to the end user. As you are using it on a simulator, it might be a rendering issue. Just check it out on a real device.

Comment: yes, thickness is the correct term. I will check it on a real device but I was just curious if this is a common issue. Thanks.

Comment: That is just a basic rendering issue no need to worry